# Optimal algorithm for merging connected parallel 3D line segments

Tags: c#, algorithm, 3d, linear-algebra

I have a sketch with 3D line segments. Each segment has start and end 3D point. My task is to merge segments if they are parallel and connected. I've implemented it on C#. This algorithm is recursive. Can this code be optimized? Can it be not recursive?

```
/// <summary>
/// Merges segments if they compose a straight line.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="segments">List of segments.</param>
/// <returns>Merged list of segments.</returns>
internal static List<Segment3d> MergeSegments(List<Segment3d> segments)
{
    var result = new List<Segment3d>(segments);
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var firstLine = result[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < result.Count; j++)
        {
            var secondLine = result[j];
            var startToStartConnected = firstLine.P1.Equals(secondLine.P1);
            var startToEndConnected = firstLine.P1.Equals(secondLine.P2);
            var endToStartConnected = firstLine.P2.Equals(secondLine.P1);
            var endToEndConnected = firstLine.P2.Equals(secondLine.P2);
                   
            if (firstLine.IsParallel(secondLine) && (startToStartConnected || startToEndConnected || endToStartConnected || endToEndConnected))
            {
                Segment3d mergedLine = null;
                if (startToStartConnected)
                {
                    mergedLine = new Segment3d(firstLine.P2, secondLine.P2);
                }

                if (startToEndConnected)
                {
                    mergedLine = new Segment3d(firstLine.P2, secondLine.P1);
                }

                if (endToStartConnected)
                {
                    mergedLine = new Segment3d(firstLine.P1, secondLine.P2);
                }

                if (endToEndConnected)
                {
                    mergedLine = new Segment3d(firstLine.P1, secondLine.P1);
                }

                // Remove duplicate.
                if (firstLine == secondLine)
                {
                    mergedLine = new Segment3d(firstLine.P1, firstLine.P2);
                }

                result.Remove(firstLine);
                result.Remove(secondLine);

                result.Add(mergedLine);
                result = MergeSegments(result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The classes Segment3D and Point3D are pretty simple:

Class Segment3D:

```
 internal class Segment3d{
    public Segment3d(Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
    {
        this.P1 = p1;
        this.P2 = p2;
    }

    public bool IsParallel(Segment3d segment)
    {
        // check if segments are parallel
        return true;
    }

    public Point3D P1 { get; }

    public Point3D P2 { get; }
}

internal class Point3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // Implement equality logic,
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the line segments that overlap like these (1,1,1)-(3,3,3) x (2,2,2)-(4,4,4)? Do you need to merge them as well? It could impact the way of merging. Also it seems to me that you are doing some stuff at least twice: first, you go over all the combinations. If you find one, you merge those two lines and then you once more go over all the combinations, even those you already checked for. Ouch.

Comment: Also, I've not used C# in a while and I don't really know which library/namespace you pulled the segment3d from. It would help to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so that it can be debugged without the need for guessing.

Comment: No, I don't need to merge overlapped segments.

Comment: @Shamis I have added code for classes Segment3D and Point3D. There logic is pretty clear. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The optimizations

You are asking about the way to remove the recursion. However that isn't the only nor the largest problem of your current solution. So I will try to give you an outline of possible directions for the optimization. Unfortunately, since your code still isn't self-contained minimal reproducible example it is rather tricky to debug. If I have time in the future, I might re-visit.

#### First step: Limiting the number of comparisons.

Currently, you are performing unnecessary number of comparisons since you compare every two possible line segments and every possible alignment that they can have. This is unnecessary.

First step to lower the number of the comparisons is to separate the line segments by their direction. Currently, when you are trying to compare two vectors, you go and check if these align. If that is the case, you proceed with the rest of the comparisons.
If we **sort** the segments by the direction, we will naturally group them into **buckets** of sort. Sorting the segments might sound weird, there are three axes to sort by. That is fine though since the only thing we actually care about is the fact, that if two normalized vectors (x,y,z) and (a,b,c) differ in at least one coordinate, they are not parallel.
This sorting can be done by implementing the `IComparable` interface and then calling `sort` method as you would normally. This has already been described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868600/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-with-icomparable-and-icomparer).
 The sorting has the complexity O(N * log(N)) which is quite a lot better than your current O(N^2) approach. (Actually, your algorithm is even worse than that since during each recursion step you do another N^2 steps. So you might be dangerously close to the O(N^4) territory. There be the dragons.)
*Note: If you are feeling adventurous and O(Nlog(N) is not enough, it could be possible to get to the O(N) territory by implementing the `System.HashCode` function for your direction vector and find the groups of parallel lines by using `Sets` or `Dictionaries`. However it might be rather tricky since floating point numbers and comparison for equality aren't exactly a friendly combination. Caution is required. Sorting should be enough for most of the use cases.*

So now we have the line segments separated by the direction vectors. Even if you proceed now with your current approach the results should be much better since we lowered the size of the groups to be compared. However we can go further.

#### Second step: Smart comparison of the segment ends.

Since you want to merge the segments if either of their endpoints align(as you covered start-start, start-end, end-start, end-end combinations in your question) we can most likely start merging any two identical points we find. The easiest way to do that is once more either sorting or hashing. Since we won't be normalizing which can result in the marginall differences, hashing should be viable. However sorting is still the more-straightforward and "safer" way to go.

One of the many ways this could be done:

1. Put all of the endpoints into single linked list as a tuple (endpoint, parent_vector). Arrays are not suitable since the deletion would be costly.
2. Sort the list by the endpoints. (Once again, you will need to implement the `IComparable` interface for your points)
3. Go through the list. Whenever the two neighboring points are equal, remove them and merge their siblings into a new line segment (Or delete one of them and the closer sibling if the neighbors are both the starting or ending point of the segment).
4. When you pass whole list, all the segments are either merged or have no more neighbors.
5. Pick up your survivors and you are done.

The complexity of this step is once again O(N * log(N)) as in the previous case. No recursion necessary and the speedup should be nice.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response. It's really helpful. I will look into it and upload the solution on github.

Comment: If it was helpful, please consider accepting the answer :-). You can always re-accept a different one if a better solution pops out. I'm glad I could be of assistance.